# Does this integration property hold in general for multivariable integration?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Does this property for univariable integration:
$$
\int f(x) dx = F(x) \; then \; F'(x) = f(x); 
$$

hold in general for multivariable integration? Thus for example in the case of two variables:

$$
\iint f(x,y) dxdy = F(x,y) \; then \; \frac{\partial F}{\partial x \partial y}(x,y) = f(x,y)
$$

It would make sense to me that this holds, given the univariate case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first displayed equation is a definition (of the symbolic expression $\int f(x) \, dx$), not a property.  None of the symbols you've written down in your second displayed equation have an accepted meaning.  For the partial derivative this could be fixed with a small tweak, and I suppose one could then define $\iint f(x, y) \, dx \, dy$ to represent a solution (or the family of all solutions) of that partial differential equation (because definitions are for free), but no one does this because there is no version of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus corresponding to this object.

Comment: @Joppe De Jonghe: just to add that the interesting thing (FTC, that the definite integral is equal to the antiderivative evaluated at the boundary) *does* have a generalization to higher dimensions, namely, the generalized Stokes's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem .  The two-dimensional analogue is Green's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem